# Best practice for adding/removing observers to/from NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, dealloc, viewdidload, nsnotificationcenter, viewdidunload

**What's the best practice for adding and removing observers to/from `NSNotificationCenter`?**

I'm wondering if adding `self` as an observer in `viewDidLoad` and removing `self` in `viewDidUnload` is sufficient. Or perhaps I should remove `self` in `dealloc` as well.

Perhaps low memory conditions need to be considered. I could see adding in `viewDidLoad` and removing in `dealloc` being problematic: `viewDidUnload` is called due to low memory... then `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is displayed again... now `self` has been added as an observer twice w/o being removed (since `dealloc` wasn't called).

**Note**: I'm considering just a basic example where `self` refers to a `UIViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually do my `UIViewController` observer registering in `viewWillAppear` and my removing in `viewWillDisappear`.

`viewWillDisappear` seems like a safer choice to me than `viewWillUnload` since the latter method only gets called in low-memory situations on iOS versions *older* than 5.0.

The most appropriate answer probably depends on what your view controller is doing. Do you expect to get (and need to react to) notifications before your view even gets displayed?  If so, maybe adding the observer in `viewDidLoad` is the right thing for you.

Comment: Interesting. So in iOS 5+ what gets called in place of viewDidUnload in low memory conditions?

Comment: `didReceiveMemoryWarning` continues to get called in case of low memory conditions. Also, check out Apple's [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (specifically the "Memory Management" section there): When a low-memory warning occurs, the UIViewController class purges its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the viewDidUnload method to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects associated with your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 8):

For iOS 9+ and OS X 10.11+, the [WWDC 2015 session 202 "What's New in Cocoa"](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407221130/http://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/202/) announced:

**NSNotificationCenter**
Deallocated observers are automatically unregistered

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
center.addObserver(self,
                   selector: "localeChanged:",
                   name: NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification,
                   object: nil)
```

No need to call

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
center.removeObserver(self,
                      name: NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification,
                      object: nil)
```

see: video at 33:27, pdf slide 241